# 8086 ASM: Turbodebugger opens text file, executing normally doesn't

Tags: assembly, x86, dos, x86-16, tasm

I'm having this little problem with an ASM assignment I'm working on. It works like a charm... when I use TD.
As I'm really new to Assembly, I really can't find what's the problem.

I need to print on screen how many characters of each ASCII code are present on a .txt file (how many a's, how many b's, and so on). I open the file using first the int 21h/3dh to create a handle, then buffering some of the bytes, working on them, and buffering the next part until the end of file is reached.
As I said, when I run it using TurboDebugger, it works perfectly. However, when I execute it simply form the command line it doesn't even create the file handle. It sets the CF after the 3dh interruption, which means an error.

I really really think that I'm not doing something I need to do, and I would appreciate help with this. Thanks!
BTW I'm using TASM to compile. I don't think posting a piece of my code would help, but if you think otherwise I will gladly modify the post.

This is the whole code, sorry about the comments in Spanish

```
NLCR       macro
           mov dl, 0dh      ;Caracter a imprimir a dl
           mov ah, 02h      ;Preparo la impresion de un caracter
           int 21h          ;Ejecuto
           mov dl, 0ah      ;Caracter a imprimir a dl
           mov ah, 02h      ;Preparo la impresion de un caracter
           int 21h          ;Ejecuto
           endm

 SData Segment para 'Data'
            msgerrorab  db  "Error al abrir el archivo.$"
            msgerrorca  db  "Error al cargar el archivo.$"
            msgnombre   db  "Ingrese el nombre del archivo a abrir: $"
            msgnoexiste db  "Error: el archivo no existe.$"
            msgimprimir db  "=========  Caracter  ==========  Cantidad  =======",10,13,"$"
            msglinea1   db "===           $"
            caracter    db  0
            msglinea2   db  "   ==========     $"
            cuantos     dw  0
            msglinea3   db  "==========",10,13,"$"
            msgtecla    db  "Presione una tecla para mostrar mas...$"
            noarchivo   db  "$$"
            nombre      db  20 Dup(?)
            buffer      db  4096 Dup(4)
            handle      dw  0
            caracteres  dw  255 Dup(0)
            cantidad    dw  0
            eof         db  0
            bytesinv    db  10 dup("$")
            bytes       db  10 dup("$") 
            contador    db  0
            
            
            
     
SData EndS

pila segment stack 'stack'
  dw 256 dup (?) 
pila ends

CSeg Segment para public 'Code'
  Begin:
       Assume CS:CSeg, DS:SData,SS:pila 
   
   

  LeeChar Proc                  ;Procedure para leer un caracter y guardarlo. Lo salva en AL
          xor ax,ax             ;Limpia el ax para guardar el resultado
          mov ah, 08h           ;Prepara el servicio para leer un caracter
          int 21h               ;Lo ejecuta
          ret                   ;Retorna
  LeeChar endP
  
  
  ImpChar Proc                  ;Similar, pero imprime un caracter
          xor ax,ax             ;Limpia el ax para guardar el resultado
          mov ah,02h            ;Prepara el servicio para imprimir un caracter
          int 21h               ;Lo ejecuta
          ret                   ;Retorna
  ImpChar endP


  
  
ImpStr Proc                 ;Similar, pero imprime un caracter
          xor ax,ax             ;Limpia el ax para guardar el resultado
          mov ah,09h            ;Prepara el servicio para imprimir un caracter
          int 21h               ;Lo ejecuta
          ret                   ;Retorna
ImpStr endP
  
ImpNum     Proc                 ;el numero en ax, el bx en 000A, dx en 0, y el di en 0.
hexadec:                        ;Con esto se pasa "a decimal", es decir convierte los caracteres a numeros para ser impresos.
           div bx               ;Divido por 10 y consigo en DL el numero de mas a la derecha
           add dx, 30h          ;Sumo 48 para pasarlo a caracter. EL MODULO QUEDA EN DX
           mov bytesinv[di], dl ;Lo guardo en el vector
           xor dx,dx            ;Limpio para volverlo a hacer
           inc di               ;Aumento el indice del vector
           cmp ax,0             ;Si ya no queda nada
           je resfinal          ;Brinco al resultado final
           jmp hexadec          ;Si todavia queda, hago el proceso de division de nuevo
       
resfinal:                       ;Inversion de los caracteres
           xor si,si
           mov al, bytesinv[di-1] ;Estas dos lineas vuelcan el vector en otro, pero en el orden que corresponde
           mov bytes[si],al     ;Pasa al nuevo vector los caracteres
           dec di               ;Decrementa para mover el indice
           inc si               ;Aumento el indice del vector
           cmp di,0             ;Si ya no queda nada
           jne resfinal
           lea dx, bytes
           xor ax,ax
           mov ah,09h
           int 21h
           ret
ImpNum     endP
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;          
;Comienzo del programa;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

inicio:   mov ax,SData          ;Con estas dos lineas, pasamos la direccion del segmento SData y lo pasamos al ds
          mov ds,ax
          mov ax,pila
          mov ss,ax
      
leernombre:
          xor di,di
          xor ax,ax             ;Limpio AX
          xor dx,dx             ;Limpio DX
          lea dx, msgnombre     ;Cargo el offset del mensaje que pide el nombre
          mov ah,09h            ;Preparo el servicio de impresion
          int 21h               ;Ejecuto
          xor ax,ax             ;Limpio AX
          xor dx,dx             ;Limpio DX
          lea dx, noarchivo     ;Carga el offset de donde voy a guardar el nombre del archivo
          mov ah,0ah            ;Preparo el servicio de entrada buffereada
          int 21h               ;Ejecuto
          nlcr                  ;New line carriage return
          xor ah,ah             ;Limpio AH
          mov al, noarchivo[1]  ;En narchivo[1] esta la cantidad de caracteres que mide el nombre de archivo
          mov di,ax             ;Lo paso al DI para usarlo como indice
          mov noarchivo[di+2],0 ;La posicion di+2 del nombre contiene el Enter, o 0ah. Lo convierto en 0.
          mov ah,3dh            ;Preparo el servicio de creacion de handle para abrir el archivo
          mov al,0              ;En modo de solo lectura
          lea dx, nombre        ;Cargo el offset del nombre en DX, sin los bytes que sobran antes
          int 21h               ;Ejecuto. El handle queda en AX
          jc  errorabrir
          mov handle,ax         ;Lo paso a su variable correspondiente
          jmp cargarbuffer
errorabrir:
          lea dx, msgerrorab        ;Cargo el offset del mensaje que pide el nombre
          mov ah,09h                ;Preparo el servicio de impresion
          int 21h       
          jmp final
errorcarga:
          lea dx, msgerrorca        ;Cargo el offset del mensaje que pide el nombre
          mov ah,09h                ;Preparo el servicio de impresion
          int 21h       
          jmp final
cargarbuffer:
          xor ax,ax             ;Limpio AX
          xor bx,bx
          lea dx, buffer        ;Cargo el offset del buffer de texto
          mov ah,3fh            ;Preparo el servicio para mover el contenido del archivo
          mov bx,handle         ;Uso el handle que me genero la int 21/3dh
          mov cx,10         ;Voy a guardar 4096 caracteres a la vez
          int 21h
          jc errorcarga
          
          mov cantidad,ax       ;Cargo la cantidad de caracteres leidos
          cmp cantidad,4096     ;Si es menor a lo que le dije que cargara, llego al end of file
          jl  endoffile         ;
          xor si,si
          xor ax,ax
          mov bx,handle
          mov ah,3eh
          int 21h
          jmp procesarbuffer
endoffile:
          mov eof,1
          jmp procesarbuffer
          
procesarbuffer:
          xor bx,bx
          xor ax,ax
          xor di,di
          xor dx,dx
          mov bl,2
          mov al,buffer[si]
          mul bl
          mov di,ax
          inc caracteres[di]
          inc si
          cmp si,cantidad
          jne procesarbuffer
          cmp eof,1
          je  imprimir
          jmp cargarbuffer

imprimir:
          xor di,di
          xor dx,dx
          xor ax,ax
          xor bx,bx
          
          mov di,0
          mov si,0
          lea dx, msgimprimir
          mov ah,09h
          int 21h

    linea:    cmp caracteres[di],0
          je  noimprime
          inc contador
          mov ax,si
          mov caracter,al
          lea dx, msglinea1
          mov ah,09h
          int 21h
          mov dl,caracter
          xor ax,ax
          mov ah,02h
          int 21h
          lea dx, msglinea2
          xor ax,ax
          mov ah,09h
          int 21h
          push di
          push si
          mov ax, caracteres[di]
          mov bx,10
          xor dx,dx
          xor di,di
          call ImpNum
          pop si
          pop di
          inc di
          inc di
          inc si
          nlcr
          cmp si,254
          je final
          cmp contador,20
          je  pidetecla
          jmp linea

    noimprime:
          inc di
          inc di
          inc si
          cmp si,254
          je final
          jmp linea
          
    pidetecla:
          lea dx, msgtecla
          xor ax,ax
          mov ah,09h
          int 21h          
          xor ax,ax
          mov ah,08h
          int 21h
          nlcr
          jmp linea
          
    final:
           xor ax,ax            ;Limpia el al y prepara el ah para la salida.
           mov ax,4c00h         ;Servicio AH=4c int 21h para salir del programa.
           int 21h              ;Llamada al DOS. Termine el programa.
    CSeg EndS                       ;Fin del segmento de código.
    End inicio                  ;Fin del programa la etiqueta al final dice en que punto debe comenzar el programa.
```

It seems that the error code that the interrupt returns is a 5, which means Access denied... Could it be because of the path file?? The file is located on the same folder that I'm compiling it on, and it's F:\dos\tasm\a.txt . I'm using DosBox, by the way.

Comment: What is content of AX after int21h/3dh? It should contains error code.

Comment: You might have some variables/registers uninitialized. I'd also check the stack size. If you are `really new to Assembly` you should consider presenting your code here.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze Done, I edited the question with the problematic code....

Comment: @rkosegi Done. It seems that the error code is a 5, which means Access denied...

Comment: I'd like to see the whole source code, not just a small part of it.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze Done, sorry if it's badly formatted... I know it's probably not the most efficient way to do it and I'm probably making a lot of mistakes, but it's my second assembly project ^^

Comment: Strange! Does the dos utility "attrib" give any clue?

Comment: Checking RBIL, I see that int 21h/3Dh uses cl as an attribute mask. Possible TD is doing something different with cl? I forget whether it's supposed to be zero of 0FFh for "any file"...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found a few bugs and fixed them. See the lines containing `;;;;` for the changes and comments. I'm not sure where exactly the problem is/was. It's working here now. Can you try it?

```
NLCR macro
        mov dl, 0dh             ;Caracter a imprimir a dl
        mov ah, 02h             ;Preparo la impresion de un caracter
        int 21h                 ;Ejecuto
        mov dl, 0ah             ;Caracter a imprimir a dl
        mov ah, 02h             ;Preparo la impresion de un caracter
        int 21h                 ;Ejecuto
endm

SData Segment para 'Data'

msgerrorab      db "Error al abrir el archivo.$"
msgerrorca      db "Error al cargar el archivo.$"
msgnombre       db "Ingrese el nombre del archivo a abrir: $"
msgnoexiste     db "Error: el archivo no existe.$"
msgimprimir     db "=========  Caracter  ==========  Cantidad  =======",10,13,"$"
msglinea1       db "===           $"
caracter        db 0
msglinea2       db "   ==========     $"
cuantos         dw 0
msglinea3       db "==========",10,13,"$"
msgtecla        db "Presione una tecla para mostrar mas...$"
noarchivo       db buffer - nombre - 1, 0 ;;;; "$$"
;;;; You must initialize the input buffer for function 2 (the max len, at least)
nombre          db 20 Dup(?)
buffer          db 4096 Dup(4)
handle          dw 0
caracteres      dw 256 Dup(0) ;;;; 255 Dup(0)
;;;; You have 256 possible chars, not 255, with 255 you can overflow into "cantidad"
cantidad        dw 0
eof             db 0
bytesinv        db 10 dup("$")
bytes           db 10 dup("$")
contador        db 0

SData EndS


pila segment stack 'stack'
  dw 256 dup (?)
pila ends


CSeg Segment para public 'Code'
Begin:
        Assume CS:CSeg, DS:SData, SS:pila

LeeChar Proc                    ;Procedure para leer un caracter y guardarlo. Lo salva en AL
        xor ax, ax              ;Limpia el ax para guardar el resultado
        mov ah, 08h             ;Prepara el servicio para leer un caracter
        int 21h                 ;Lo ejecuta
        ret                     ;Retorna
LeeChar endP

ImpChar Proc                    ;Similar, pero imprime un caracter
        xor ax, ax              ;Limpia el ax para guardar el resultado
        mov ah, 02h             ;Prepara el servicio para imprimir un caracter
        int 21h                 ;Lo ejecuta
        ret                     ;Retorna
ImpChar endP

ImpStr Proc                     ;Similar, pero imprime un caracter
        xor ax, ax              ;Limpia el ax para guardar el resultado
        mov ah, 09h             ;Prepara el servicio para imprimir un caracter
        int 21h                 ;Lo ejecuta
        ret                     ;Retorna
ImpStr endP

ImpNum Proc                     ;el numero en ax, el bx en 000A, dx en 0, y el di en 0.
hexadec:                        ;Con esto se pasa "a decimal", es decir convierte los caracteres a numeros para ser impresos.
        div bx                  ;Divido por 10 y consigo en DL el numero de mas a la derecha
        add dx, 30h             ;Sumo 48 para pasarlo a caracter. EL MODULO QUEDA EN DX
        mov bytesinv[di], dl    ;Lo guardo en el vector
        xor dx, dx              ;Limpio para volverlo a hacer
        inc di                  ;Aumento el indice del vector
        cmp ax, 0               ;Si ya no queda nada
        je resfinal             ;Brinco al resultado final
        jmp hexadec             ;Si todavia queda, hago el proceso de division de nuevo

resfinal:                       ;Inversion de los caracteres
        xor si, si
resfinal2: ;;;;
        mov al, bytesinv[di-1]  ;Estas dos lineas vuelcan el vector en otro, pero en el orden que corresponde
        mov bytes[si], al       ;Pasa al nuevo vector los caracteres
        dec di                  ;Decrementa para mover el indice
        inc si                  ;Aumento el indice del vector
        cmp di, 0               ;Si ya no queda nada
        jne resfinal2 ;;;; resfinal
;;;; You don't want to be storing all digits at 'bytes[si=0]', overwriting each other
        mov bytes[si], "$"      ;;;;
;;;; You must terminate the string with '$' for function 9, you don't want garbage
        lea dx, bytes
        xor ax, ax
        mov ah, 09h
        int 21h
        ret
ImpNum endP

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;Comienzo del programa;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

inicio:
        mov ax, SData           ;Con estas dos lineas, pasamos la direccion del segmento SData y lo pasamos al ds
        mov ds, ax
;;;;        mov ax, pila
;;;;        mov ss, ax
;;;; .EXEs set up SS:SP for you!

leernombre:
        xor di, di
        xor ax, ax              ;Limpio AX
        xor dx, dx              ;Limpio DX
        lea dx, msgnombre       ;Cargo el offset del mensaje que pide el nombre
        mov ah, 09h             ;Preparo el servicio de impresion
        int 21h                 ;Ejecuto
        xor ax, ax              ;Limpio AX
        xor dx, dx              ;Limpio DX
        lea dx, noarchivo       ;Carga el offset de donde voy a guardar el nombre del archivo
        mov ah, 0ah             ;Preparo el servicio de entrada buffereada
        int 21h                 ;Ejecuto
        nlcr                    ;New line carriage return
        xor ah, ah              ;Limpio AH
        mov al, noarchivo[1]    ;En narchivo[1] esta la cantidad de caracteres que mide el nombre de archivo
        mov di, ax              ;Lo paso al DI para usarlo como indice
        mov noarchivo[di+2],0   ;La posicion di+2 del nombre contiene el Enter, o 0ah. Lo convierto en 0.
        mov ah, 3dh             ;Preparo el servicio de creacion de handle para abrir el archivo
        mov al, 0               ;En modo de solo lectura
        lea dx, nombre          ;Cargo el offset del nombre en DX, sin los bytes que sobran antes
        int 21h                 ;Ejecuto. El handle queda en AX
        jc  errorabrir
        mov handle, ax          ;Lo paso a su variable correspondiente
        jmp cargarbuffer

errorabrir:
        lea dx, msgerrorab      ;Cargo el offset del mensaje que pide el nombre
        mov ah, 09h             ;Preparo el servicio de impresion
        int 21h
        jmp final

errorcarga:
        lea dx, msgerrorca      ;Cargo el offset del mensaje que pide el nombre
        mov ah, 09h             ;Preparo el servicio de impresion
        int 21h
        jmp final

cargarbuffer:
        xor ax, ax              ;Limpio AX
        xor bx, bx
        lea dx, buffer          ;Cargo el offset del buffer de texto
        mov ah, 3fh             ;Preparo el servicio para mover el contenido del archivo
        mov bx, handle          ;Uso el handle que me genero la int 21/3dh
        mov cx, 4096 ;;;; 10              ;Voy a guardar 4096 caracteres a la vez
;;;; You wanted 4096 and implemented logic for 4096, so use 4096.
        int 21h
        jc errorcarga

        mov cantidad, ax        ;Cargo la cantidad de caracteres leidos
        cmp cantidad, 4096      ;Si es menor a lo que le dije que cargara, llego al end of file
        jl  endoffile           ;
        xor si, si
;;;;        xor ax, ax
;;;;        mov bx, handle
;;;;        mov ah, 3eh
;;;;        int 21h
;;;; You had the condition for file closing wrong
        jmp procesarbuffer

endoffile:
        xor si, si              ;;;;
        xor ax, ax              ;;;;
        mov bx, handle          ;;;;
        mov ah, 3eh             ;;;;
        int 21h                 ;;;;
;;;; You had the condition for file closing wrong

        mov eof, 1

        cmp cantidad, 0         ;;;;
        je  imprimir            ;;;;
;;;; The original code at 'procesarbuffer' wouldn't work with 'cantidad'=0

        jmp procesarbuffer

procesarbuffer:
        xor bx, bx
        xor ax, ax
        xor di, di
        xor dx, dx
        mov bl, 2
        mov al, buffer[si]
        mul bl
        mov di, ax
        inc caracteres[di]
        inc si
        cmp si, cantidad
        jne procesarbuffer
        cmp eof, 1
        je  imprimir
        jmp cargarbuffer

imprimir:
        xor di, di
        xor dx, dx
        xor ax, ax
        xor bx, bx

        mov di, 0
        mov si, 0
        lea dx, msgimprimir
        mov ah, 09h
        int 21h

linea:        
        cmp caracteres[di], 0
        je  noimprime
        inc contador
        mov ax, si
        mov caracter, al
        lea dx, msglinea1
        mov ah, 09h
        int 21h
        mov dl, caracter
        xor ax, ax
        mov ah, 02h
        int 21h
        lea dx, msglinea2
        xor ax, ax
        mov ah, 09h
        int 21h
        push di
        push si
        mov ax, caracteres[di]
        mov bx, 10
        xor dx, dx
        xor di, di
        call ImpNum
        pop si
        pop di
        inc di
        inc di
        inc si
        nlcr
        cmp si, 254
        je final
        cmp contador, 20
        je  pidetecla
        jmp linea

noimprime:
        inc di
        inc di
        inc si
        cmp si, 254
        je final
        jmp linea

pidetecla:
        mov contador, 0 ;;;;
;;;; You want to wait for a key after each 20 lines, not just after the first 20
        lea dx, msgtecla
        xor ax, ax
        mov ah, 09h
        int 21h
        xor ax, ax
        mov ah, 08h
        int 21h
        nlcr
        jmp linea

final:
        xor ax, ax              ;Limpia el al y prepara el ah para la salida.
        mov ax, 4c00h           ;Servicio AH=4c int 21h para salir del programa.
        int 21h                 ;Llamada al DOS. Termine el programa.

CSeg EndS                       ;Fin del segmento de codigo.

End inicio                      ;Fin del programa la etiqueta al final dice en que punto debe comenzar el programa.
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!! Some of the bugs you found are actually changes I made while debugging, but most were my bad ^^. I actually figured it out, although I still don't know what caused the problem. It turns out that after the jump to procesarbuffer, SI got somehow filled with garbage... I just had to clean it with an XOR again, and it worked. Thanks again!